# how to access a image variable in another button method in java fx

Tags: java, javafx

```
openButton.setOnAction((final ActionEvent X) -> {
            File newfile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);

            Image userselectedimage = new Image(file.toURI().toString());

more code


 newactionbutton.setOnAction((final ActionEvent X) ->{
              * i need access to the user selected image variable here *
}
```

I need to access the variable userselectedimage (it is a image selected by the user for the background) in another button. is it possible since the scope is defined in that onclick action to access that variable in another button? I need it since its the users selected picture (it is a file that the user selects). I tried defining it outside of the method wiht a static variable but that didn't work either, so im out of ideas.

thanks.

Comment: work through a tutorial about java language basics, apply what you learned to your context, when stuck come back with a [mcve] demonstrating what's wrong.

Answer (score -1):

```
Image userselectedimage = null;    
openButton.setOnAction((final ActionEvent X) -> {
            File newfile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
            userselectedimage = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
}

 newactionbutton.setOnAction((final ActionEvent X) ->{
              userselectedimage.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: I believe this code would fail to compile because userselectedimage is defined as non-final local variable, for which attempts are being to made to assign a value in one lambda and reference its value in another lambda.  See: https://www.baeldung.com/java-lambda-effectively-final-local-variables